# Why the files directive doesn't work in Apache's httpd.conf?

Tags: apache

I had to `noindex` pdf files. I did it many times, so in this case, I used a `files` directive for adding `noindex` header with `X-Robots-Tag`, like [Google recommends](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag):

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

When I have used this before, it worked like a charm. But in this case, I realized no `X-Robots-Tag` on its own, neither its content (`noindex`, `nofollow`) in header. Mod_headers was enabled.

I tried

```
<FilesMatch ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</FilesMatch>
```

with no luck.

After many further tries and errors I've got it working with

```
<LocationMatch ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</LocationMatch>
```

But I don't really understand why the rule I used for years stopped working and the rule I blindly tried, suddenly works.

Could somebody explain it to me?

Comment: Try placing it inside your virtual hosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#files) states that FilesMatch takes a regular expression pattern `<FilesMatch regexp>` and is preferred over using `<Files ~ "regexp">`

> The <FilesMatch> directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives by filename, just as the <Files> directive does. However, it accepts a regular expression.

In my experience with RegEx, this means using a wildcard to match all, rather than the normal <Files> directive which matches on a substring.

As for matching all named files in an expression, that means a small tweak is required to your existing code:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</FilesMatch>
```

If you expect to have a file named `.pdf` that you also need to exclude, replace `+` in that expression with `*`. This is due to how RegEx matches:

- `.` Match any character, once.
- `+` The previous modifier or block must occur one or more times
- `*` The previous modifier or block may occur zero or more times

This means `.+` matches all files with **at least one character** before `.pdf` in the filename, and `.*` matches **all files** ending on `.pdf`.

As for an explanation on why your `Files` directive doesn't work:
The Files directive may be overridden by other Files directives appearing later in the same configuration  or within a `.htaccess` file in the directory you're keeping the pdf files in. Furthermore, there's an order in which the directives are handled and they can all override previous steps:
`Directory` < `Files` in `Directory` < `.htaccess` < `Files` in `.htaccess` < `Location`. So it's most probably a different part of the configuration that ignores the `Files` directive

Comment: I'm trying to understand: why rules, which always worked, stopped to work, and why a rule, which i never used and realized in this context, suddenly works.

Comment: @Evgeniy I edited the answer to include an explanation of why the `Files` directive is being ignored. I can't be absolutely certain that this is the case though, since I don't know the full Apache configuration